# Python simple regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have a pattern:

```
hourPattern = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

And match against the compiled pattern

```
hourStart = hourPattern.match('Sat Jan 28 01:15:00 GMT 2012')
```

When I print `hourStart` it gives me None. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Match expects the found value to be at the beginning of the string.  You want search.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = re.compile('\d+')
>>>
>>> s2 = 'a123'
>>>
>>> s.match(s2)
>>> s.search(s2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01E29AD8>
```

Comment: @Jirico - Happy to help.  Be sure to mark answers as accepted so that other users know you've received the help you need.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Switch from the *match* method to the *search* method:

```
>>> hourPattern = re.compile('\d{2}:\d{2}')
>>> hourStart = hourPattern.search('Sat Jan 28 01:15:00 GMT 2012')
>>> hourStart.group()
'01:15'
```